# Minimal polynomial questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I have to find the minimal polynomial for $\cos(2\pi/5)$ and $\sin(2\pi/5)$ and I'd like to know what is wrong with my attempt:

$\cos(4\pi/5)=\cos(6\pi/5) = 4\cos^3(2\pi/5)-3\cos(2\pi/5)$, that gives $\cos^3(2\pi/5)= (1/4)\cos(4\pi/5)+(3/4)\cos(2\pi/5)$

$\cos^0(2\pi/5)=1$

$\cos(2\pi/5)=\cos(2\pi/5)$

$\cos^2(2\pi/5) =(1/2)\cos(4\pi/5)+(1/2)$

$\cos^3(2\pi/5)=(1/4)\cos(4\pi/5)+(3/4)\cos(2\pi/5)$

---

$\cos^3(2\pi/5)-(1/2)\cos^2(2\pi/5)-(3/4)\cos(2\pi/5)+(1/4)=0$,
then $\cos(2\pi/5)$ is a root of $t^3-(1/2)t^2-(3/4)t+(1/4)$. But it is not a minimal polynomial. What should I do now? Please, help.

Comment: The polynomial seems to vanish at $t=1$. Divide by $t-1$ then. We know that $\cos(2\pi/5)$ is not $1$. So, we will not lose that root after that division.

Comment: Thank you so much. How about sin(2pi/5) ? should I do the same steps?

Comment: You could. It is not the only way, there are many.

Comment: I know there are many ways to find, but this is my way :) and I would like to know others, Please, post the answer so that I can study more.

Answer (score 2):

We can try it also this other way:

$$\begin{align}w&=e^{2\pi i/5}=\cos(2\pi/5)+i\sin(2\pi/5)\\w^{-1}&=e^{-2\pi i/5}=\cos(2\pi/5)-i\sin(2\pi/5)\end{align}$$

and $$w^5=e^{2\pi i}=1$$

We need a polynomial that vanishes at $c=\dfrac{w+w^{-1}}{2}=\cos(2\pi/5)$.

Since $0=w^5-1=(w-1)(w^4+w^3+w^2+w+1)$. We know that $w\neq1$ therefore $$w^4+w^3+w^2+w+1=0$$

We do this trick with the equation above

$$0=w^2\left(w^2+w^{-2}+w+w^{-1}+1\right)=w^2\left[\left(w+w^{-1}\right)^2+\left(w+w^{-1}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right]$$

Therefore $$(2c)^2+2c+\frac{1}{2}=0.$$

Now try to imitate this computation for $s=\dfrac{w-w^{-1}}{2i}=\sin(2\pi/5)$.

I have to leave now, check if I did the computations correct. You can edit the answer yourself, I think.

Comment: Woahh, It's beautiful. I got all but the last step. Do we have to prove the answer is irreducible on Q? How?

Comment: @user73195 In this case we get quadratic polynomials. Proving that they are irreducible can be done just computing their roots and seeing they are not rational.